# React Native network request failed HTTPS

Tags: react-native, networking, https, fetch

I am building RN app with expo that depends on many http requests. I agreed with my backend that we will use HTTPS certificate, but somehow my Android emulator is throwing me errors for these requests. Once we tried only HTTP request it worked. This error occurs when I try to fetch some data:

```
Network request failed
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:473:29 in xhr.onerror
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I already tried to modify AndroidManifest.xml file with

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"
```

but still no result. We have our own server with IP, which when I try to access through browser gives me response I want in my app. So it looks like server is working fine with everything around it only my app doesnt want to fetch this data. Has anyone solved this issue with HTTPS requests please?

Comment: Have you tried using an http request library like apisauce?

Comment: Not yet, but do you think this can help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One side note - I am trying to access my server through IP address but I guess this shouldnt be the problem my get request looks like this:

```
const res = await fetch('https://147.175.121.250/info/listOfUsers');
const json = await res.json();
```